# Mysql search fields in all rows that match a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

First of all, I know the post title is not describing the situation properly, I will take any advice to change it.

Here is the situation:
I have a table with 3 columns: itemName, keyField and value,
here's an example:

```
itemName  |   keyField   |   value
-----------------------------------
pen       |   color      |   blue
car       |   color      |   green
pen       |   weight     |   10 grams
pen       |   weight     |   10 grams
chair     |   price      |   $30.00
chair     |   color      |   blue
shoes     |   brand      |   whatever
```

As you can see, the table is meant to store any attribute of an item dynamically.
I need a query to search all items with color: blue and weight: 10 grams, in this case that's the pen.
It should be able to also search all blue items (pen and chair).

Mysql: 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select itemname
from t
where (keyfield, value) in ( ('color', 'blue'), ('weight', '10 grams') )
group by itemname
having count(*) = 2;  -- both match
```

Comment: to clarify: this solution works in my case due to the fact that the itemName-keyField combination is unique. It does not work in cases where itemName-keyField can be repeated. The key I suppose would be in the count (*) = 2 condition.

Comment: @ArmandoRodríguezAcosta . . . The logic can be tweaked for that case as well.  The `count(*)` is the simplest method and it matches the need in the question.